# Akka persistence custom java plugin

Tags: java, akka, akka-persistence

I am currently in the process of writing my own plugin for the `Akka` `SyncWriteJournal` API to implement the connection with `HSQLDB`.

The problem is that I do no understand the requirements for the method `doAsyncReplayMessages`. It states that it needs to return a future and that all the messages should be called by `replayCallback`.

Let's say that I have a query which returns a list of messages: `List<Message> messages`. Can anyone provide a minimal example (with explanation) of how to use `replayCallback`, and `Future` to implement the method correctly by using that list? How would `replayCallback` and `Future` work together and what should be returned by the method `doAsyncReplayMessages`?

Thanks!

-Edit-

With the help of some comments I've whipped up an implementation which is not complete but incorporates the idea proposed:

```
public Future<Void> doAsyncReplayMessages(final String persistenceId, long fromSequenceNr, long toSequenceNr, long max,
        final Procedure<PersistentRepr> replayCallback) {
    final ExecutionContext ec = context().system().dispatcher();

    final Future<Void> future = Futures.future(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            final List<Message> messages = getMessages();
            for (int i = 0; i < feedbackList.size(); i++) {
                replayCallback.apply(
                        new PersistentImpl(messages.get(i), i, persistenceId, false, null, null));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, ec);

    return future;
}
```

As you might see it missed a few key concepts I'm still missing. The PersistentImpl needs one argument `Seq<String> confirm` which is `null` still. And perhaps more importantly I'm return `null` since the future expects `Void` as return type and I'm not sure how implement that. It currently throws a NPE:

```
[ERROR] [08/28/2014 12:31:19.582] [akkaSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://akkaSystem/system/journal] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at akka.persistence.journal.japi.AsyncRecovery.asyncReadHighestSequenceNr(AsyncRecovery.scala:26)
    at akka.persistence.journal.SyncWriteJournal$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SyncWriteJournal.scala:53)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at akka.persistence.journal.japi.SyncWriteJournal.aroundReceive(SyncWriteJournal.scala:16)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: hey have succeeded? i would like to find a custom java akka persistence plugin example

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap your blocking operation in the Future, such as: `Future { fetchStuff() }`.

You can refer to [dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc: JdbcSyncWriteJournal](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/jdbc/journal/JdbcSyncWriteJournal.scala#L78) for a full blown implementation of a synchronous journal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot read scala (my implementation is in Java). Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Here are the docs for using Futures from Java: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/java/futures.html#Use_Directly

You can call Futures.future(callable, executionContext) where the callable would fetch the List<Messages>, call the replyCallback on each of them and then finish. That callable must have a return type of Void to match the expected return type Future<Void>.